# Nginx returning 404 when trying get subroute in dockerized react app

Tags: docker, nginx, react-router, serve

I have a react app served with serve on docker.
I use Nginx to rewrite requests to my  app with the following config:

```
http {
    upstream myapp_servers {
        server 1.2.3.4:8000;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp_servers;
    }
}
```

When I access my app with myapp.com it works fine.
If i want to access a subroute on my app like myapp.com/route nginx returns 404 error,
`try_files $uri index.html` only works if nginx serves static files.
How can i solve this issue for dockerized react app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, the issue *was not* with Nginx.
What happened is that I used `vercel\serve` for my deployment server and i had to run it in single mode with `-s`, also i had to remove `homepage: "."`
from my `package.json` and now the application works properly in production.